# Underflow in Matlab

Tags: matlab, underflow

Is it a good practice to manually set numbers with large negative exponential like 1e-300 to zero to avoid underflow in Matlab?

If not how can we avoid harm of underflow when implementing functions like log(1+exp(x))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you get trouble when adding very large and very small values, because this can lead to a high relative error. Get rid of this summation (1+exp(x)), it quickly runs out of the range of double values when x is large.

```
log(1+exp(x))
log(1+1/exp(x))*exp(x))
log(1+1/exp(x))+log(exp(x))
log(1+1/exp(x))+x
```

An alternative is the use of vpa:

```
log(1+exp(vpa(10^6)))
```

very slow, but you get a result with the configured precision.

I never saw a case where manually setting small values to zero was a good solution, typically comparing with a tolerance is better.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by comparing with tolerance? Maybe we both mean the same thing?

Comment: Instead of `x==0` you have to use a small tolerance `abs(x)<t`, but there is no good rule to find a proper tolerance.

Comment: Sure, by setting small values to zero I meant first finding small values by a threshold like abs(x)<t, then setting them to zero, e.g. if abs(x)<t then x=0.